# WPF C# runtime graphical editor on form. Easiest solution

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, visualization

I am trying to find a solution to creating a graphical designer that will allow users to modify objects using a graphical editor in runtime.

The idea is to create a type of network diagram that displays how network devices are connected. I would like a user to connect objects together on here and allow the diagram to display connection arrows that are automatically drawn based on the number of connections etc.

I would like configuation in my editor to be saved  in my database and I am using Entity Framework. So I will probably add rows for each object and reference a child object's ID to show that it has something connected to it.

This is what I was thinking:
[image]

What would be the least time consuming (easiest) way to achieve this? Is there a framework or API available that someone could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There's a series of codeproject articles could be interesting to get you started:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4

( I've not tried the code or looked at it in depth. )